# does the sharedscripts setting for logrotate apply to all processed logs, or only those in the current context?

Tags: logrotate

So I have a number of apache logs I like to handle with logrotate on a developer box. Some of them are for user sandboxes, others are for staging versions and such.

The logrotate config looks like:

```
/srv/www/logs/beta/*log
/srv/www/logs/www/*log
/home/developerx/logs/*.log {
    daily
    rotate 100
    olddir archive
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /sbin/service httpd reload > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

I would like to customize some of the settings for beta versus a sandbox, like rotate 10 instead of 100 for a sandbox. I could create a new context for this, but if I do the postrotate "reload" for multiple contexts I worry that the process will be reloaded multiple times.

As a secondary question, is there any way to determine the order in which logrotate will process these entries? Alphabetical by filename, and first-to-last within a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you write a separate entry, and it will have a reload command, the http server will be reloaded twice.

I believe logrotate applies the rules just as you described. It includes files in logrotate.d directory and just works through them, first to last entry. I have a logrotate monitoring based on this fact: the last rule in one particularly tricky set of files has a postrotate script which echoes `date +%j` to a status file.

You can check all of the above with `logrotate -d -f /etc/logrotate.conf` where -d stands for 'debug'.

Apache, though, can use rotatelogs as a custom logger, *and* the CustomLog directive can be different for each of sites you have, so you can treat differenrt logs the different way and eliminate that reload problem.

Comment: Good to know about Apache and rotatelogs, though it doesn't appear to support rotation into a different directory. (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/rotatelogs.html)